# Issues with the =FILTER() function google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter

Perhaps my understanding of how the `=FILTER()` function works is incorrect, but I was under the impression that it was
`=FILTER(range, condition 1, [condition 2], ...)`

which means this:

`=FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, 'Item Database'!R4:R="Heavy Armor", 'Item Database'!R5:R="Light Armor")`
should return a list of items from `'Item Database'!A5:A` who's `R` column matched either `"Heavy Armor"` or `"Light Armor"`

As I said, it is possible my understanding is just incorrect, but all I'm getting is an `N/A` error telling me that no items match the filter result

Here's a link to a copy of the spreadsheet as well
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oXLbc9vkjuWYU60xhsYsT3vv7utOJswVjwJUWS3XpF0/edit?usp=sharing 

+++++Edit
With some further fooling around with it, I'm thinking that BOTH conditon 1 and condition 2 must be met in order to fit the criteria. Going to try this:
`=FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, 'Item Database'!R5:R="Heavy Armor")&FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, 'Item Database'!R5:R="Light Armor"`
Above attempt populated one cell instead of cascading down the entire column like my `Weapon` and `All` lists do.

Have also attempted:
`=FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, 'Item Database'!R5:R="*"&"Armor")`
`=FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, 'Item Database'!R5:R="*"&" Armor")`
`=FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, 'Item Database'!R5:R="*Armor")`

Answer (score 1):

Final solution turned out to be:
`=FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, ('Item Database'!R5:R="Heavy Armor") + ('Item Database'!R5:R="Light Armor"))`
Marking this as answered so no one's time is wasted, yay for trial and error!

Comment: The reason why your initial function doesn't work `=FILTER(range, condition 1, [condition 2], ...)` is because it performs `AND` condition where both condition 1 and condition 2 should be true. But in reality you need to use `OR` in your condition 1 and condition 2 which was implemented using `+` operator

Comment: I appreciate the explanation! Only reason I stumbled upon my solution with the good ol "keep throwing things at the problem til something fixes it" method, but its nice to know what I actually did

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=FILTER('Item Database'!A5:A, 
 REGEXMATCH('Item Database'!R5:R, "Heavy Armor|Light Armor"))
```